# r function to conditionally match parcial strings

Tags: r, string, matching, partial

I have two big datasets, I would like to subset some columns in order to use the data.
My problem is that the reference column for subsetting is not completely matching. So I would like to be able to match for the part of the strings that are the same.

Here a simpler example:

```
ref_df <- data.frame("reference" = c("swietenia macrophylla",                       
                                     "azadirachta indica",                        
                                     "cedrela odorata",                               
                                     "ochroma pyramidale",                            
                                     "tectona grandis",                               
                                     "tamarindus indica",                             
                                     "cariniana pyriformis",                          
                                     "paquita quinata",                               
                                     "albizia saman",                                 
                                     "enterolobium cyclocarpum",                      
                                     "tapirira guianensis",                           
                                     "dipteryx oleifera"),
                     "values" = c(rnorm(12)))

tofind_df <- c("swietenia macrophylla and try try",                       
           "azadirachta indica",                        
           "tamarindus indica (bla bla)",                             
           "tara",                          
           "bla bla (paquita quinata)",                               
           "prosopis pallida",                                 
           "dipteryx oleifera")
```

So I try to keep all the values of ref_df that have a name that matches even partially in tofond_df, but it only matches if they are the same.

```
 finale <- ref_df[ref_df$reference %in% tofind_df$names,]
```

I tried with grepl as well, but I couldn't find the solution.

My ideal finale should look like this:

```
                  reference       values
1     swietenia macrophylla -0.459001383    
2        azadirachta indica -0.430014486
3         tamarindus indica -0.541887328
4           paquita quinata -0.003572792
5         dipteryx oleifera -0.855659901
```

Please, think about two big df and not this easier situation.

Comment: Why do "tamarindus indica" and "paquita quinata" match, but "swietenia macrophylla" does not?

Comment: Sorry, my error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use `sapply` to get the results from `grepl` for every element

```
ref_df[sapply(ref_df$reference, function(x) any(grepl(x, tofind_df))),]

               reference     values
1  swietenia macrophylla  1.4482830
2     azadirachta indica  0.9037943
6      tamarindus indica -0.2994678
8        paquita quinata  0.4895183
12     dipteryx oleifera -1.1652528
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use group_by and filter from dplyr and str_detect from stringr:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

ref_df %>% 
  mutate(reference = as.character(reference))%>% #reference is factor. Making it a character
  group_by(reference) %>%
  filter(any(str_detect(tofind_df,reference)))%>% #Finding if there are any matches between each reference name and any of the strings in the tofind_df
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 5 x 2
  reference             values
  <chr>                  <dbl>
1 swietenia macrophylla -0.456
2 azadirachta indica    -1.08 
3 tamarindus indica     -0.428
4 paquita quinata       -0.937
5 dipteryx oleifera      0.816
```